# remover a extensão php e forçar toda pagina como https via htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, https, url-amigavel

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma regrar em .htaccess para forçar o https em todas as paginas e ocultar a extensão .php . Ele esta hospedado na kinghost e ja tenho o certificado.
Tenho os codigos separados mas  não consegui fazer as duas coisa juntas onde toda pagina contenham o https e sem extensão .php exemplo  : https://menudominio/fale-conosco

codigo htaccess para remover a extensão .php

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

codigo htaccess para forçar https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seusitecomhttps.com.br/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar na ordem desejada e sempre adicionar a flag `L` para cada `RewriteRule` que não deve se misturar, é somente necessário um `on`

Deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redireciona para HTTPS se estiver na porta 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seusitecomhttps.com.br/$1 [R,L]

# Reescreve as URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

O ultimo `[L]` que adicionei para o caso especifico é desnecessário, mas acaso venha adicionar novas regras que não tem relação com `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` será bom para "evitar" conflitos, claro que depende muito das novas regras.